# How can i remove duplicates for a endless generator?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

if i have a random sample generator, which sample from a large space(which is cant enumerate).

```
def random_generator(n=3):
  ####  .....  ####
  yield random.choice(large_space)  ## here i just use a simple random, but in real, i use many method to get the random
```

if the large space can enumerated, the problem will be easy.

But for this large space, it cant be enumerated for some reason(it generate from recursion, which makes the valid sample is too too large, if i call the genertor of this space, next() will flood my memory, if you want to know the details of this odd generator, please see this: [How can i make a generator yield fast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083529/how-can-i-make-a-generator-yield-fast?noredirect=1#comment115063694_65083529))

based on that, is there any methods can make my random_generator never produce duplicate sample?(effectivity is very important)

Comment: You could use set

Comment: you could check if the generated sample is already in your group if it is delete the sample  if not include it

Comment: @reece thanks! it will use a lot of memory. but i think memory use cant be avoided,

Comment: for the memory problem you could delete the duplicate sample by using del var_that_holds_sample

Comment: are the `large_space` values hashable?

Comment: @TomWojcik yes, it is

Comment: Consider randomly shuffling a subset of the large space and then just have your generator iterate over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking to avoid generating duplicate random numbers and want to save space by not storing the previously generated random numbers. You could use a bloom filter.

```
from bloom_filter import BloomFilter

bloom = BloomFilter(max_elements=n, error_rate=0.1)
large_space = list(range(1000000)) # Some large number

def random_generator(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        new_number = random.choice(large_space)
        while new_number not in bloom:
            new_number = random.choice(large_space)
        bloom.add(new_number)
        yield new_number
```